# unable to crawl from indeed.com

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

I am not able to run this script. Can someone guide me what exactly is wrong this script? are all xpaths correct?

I feel that this part is wrong:

```
item['job_title'] = site.select('h2/a/@title').extract()
link_url= site.select('h2/a/@href').extract()
```

as the xpath is not correct.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from indeeda.items import IndeedaItem
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
import time
import sys

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'indeed'
    allowed_domains = ['indeed.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date?']
    rules = ( 
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/jobs.q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date$','q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date&start=[0-9]+$',),deny=('/my/mysearches', '/preferences', '/advanced_search','/my/myjobs')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),

        )
    def parse_next_site(self, response):

        item = response.request.meta['item']
        item['source_url'] = response.url
        item['source_page_body'] = response.body
        item['crawl_timestamp'] =  time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            return item 

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('\n Crawling  %s\n' % response.url)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select("//div[@class='row ' or @class='row lastRow']")
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = IndeedaItem()
            item['job_title'] = site.select('h2/a/@title').extract()
            link_url= site.select('h2/a/@href').extract()
            item['link_url'] = link_url
            item['crawl_url'] = response.url
            item['location'] = site.select("span[@class='location']/text()").extract()
            tem['summary'] = site.select("//table/tr/td/span[@class='summary']").extract()
            item['source'] = site.select("table/tr/td/span[@class='source']/text()").extract()
            item['found_date'] = site.select("table/tr/td/span[@class='date']/text()").extract()
            #item['source_url'] = self.get_source(link_url)
            request = Request("http://www.indeed.com" + item['link_url'][0], callback=self.parse_next_site)
                    request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

            items.append(item)
        return 
SPIDER=MySpider()
```

Following is the error log:

```
hakuna@hakuna-Inspiron-3542:~/indeeda$ scrapy crawl indeed
/home/hakuna/indeeda/indeeda/spiders/test.py:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
/home/hakuna/indeeda/indeeda/spiders/test.py:3: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
/home/hakuna/indeeda/indeeda/spiders/test.py:5: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
/home/hakuna/indeeda/indeeda/spiders/test.py:5: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors.sgml` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
/home/hakuna/indeeda/indeeda/spiders/test.py:15: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SgmlLinkExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please use scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/jobs.q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date$','q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date&start=[0-9]+$',),deny=('/my/mysearches', '/preferences', '/advanced_search','/my/myjobs')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
2016-01-21 21:31:22 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: indeeda)
2016-01-21 21:31:22 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2016-01-21 21:31:22 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'indeeda.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['indeeda.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'indeeda'}
2016-01-21 21:31:22 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-01-21 21:31:22 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date?> (referer: None)
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date?> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 73, in _parse_response
    for request_or_item in self._requests_to_follow(response):
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 52, in _requests_to_follow
    links = [l for l in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response) if l not in seen]
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/sgml.py", line 138, in extract_links
    links = self._extract_links(body, response.url, response.encoding, base_url)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py", line 103, in _extract_links
    return self.link_extractor._extract_links(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/sgml.py", line 36, in _extract_links
    self.feed(response_text)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 174, in goahead
    k = self.parse_declaration(i)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/markupbase.py", line 98, in parse_declaration
    decltype, j = self._scan_name(j, i)
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/markupbase.py", line 392, in _scan_name
    % rawdata[declstartpos:declstartpos+20])
  File "/home/hakuna/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 111, in error
    raise SGMLParseError(message)
SGMLParseError: expected name token at "<!\\\\])/g, '\\\\$1').\n "
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 245,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 28427,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 22, 3, 31, 23, 795599),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/SGMLParseError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 22, 3, 31, 23, 504391)}
2016-01-21 21:31:23 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

It says the deprecated for most of the libraries.

Comment: you are talking about running the script, but then incorrect xpath, show the logs or error you are getting.

Comment: @eLRuLL: I have added logs, thank you!

Comment: why do you have `SPIDER=MySpider()` at the end of the file? how are you running the spider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SgmlLinkExtractor` is being deprecated, use `LinkExtractor` instead.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

...
    rules = ( 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/jobs.q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date$','q=linux&l=Chicago&sort=date&start=[0-9]+$',),deny=('/my/mysearches', '/preferences', '/advanced_search','/my/myjobs')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
...
```

Comment: I have updated that, but when I try to save it in csv, it saves it as blank csv file.

I used this command: scrapy crawl indeed -o dees.csv -t csv

I hope to follow up on the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that a different problem, first run just `scrapy crawl indeed --logfile="mylog.log"` to check if the spider is working, giving errors, returning items, etc, and when everything is working, then think of saving your data. Your problem is mostly about your xpath, maybe there is nothing in `sites`, check that.

Comment: I have edited into the answer, errors which are showing up. I have not posted much questions here so I don't know where to post the error log